# Escape @ in wget for FTP login

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, escaping

i need to download all files from an FTP address using wget.
I'm currently using this code:

```
wget -m ftp://user:password@ip.of.old.host
```

However, my username for accessing FTP is something like user@domain, so i would get

```
wget -m ftp://user@domain:password@ip.of.old.host
```

The command fails because of the @ in the username field.
How can i escape the @?
I wasn't able to find any answer on Google.

Comment: I think you can do wget -m "ftp://user@domain:password@ip.of.old.host"

Comment: Does not work...it tries to access only with user and not user@domain.

Comment: The protocol ftp:// does not matter. The problem is that wget recognizes the @ as the separator for user and password and not as a part of the username.

Comment: What if you use `--user "user@domain" --password "password" ip.of.old.host` ?

Comment: Did not work. I downloaded the main site but without accessing the FTP(it was a simple HTTP request, your command does not deal with FTP)

Comment: Tried to use --user "user@domain" --password "password" ftp://ip.of.old.host and seemed to work, but i get wrong login.(ip.of.old.host prepending ftp://)

Comment: Login error was a server issue. It works now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution was to use

```
wget -m --user "user@domain" --password "password" ftp://ip.of.old.host
```

As fedorqui suggested but adding ftp:// before ip.of.old.host.

Thanks!

Comment: Nice to see it was this!

Comment: What if there is a wget version shipped which doesn't support --password flag? For example: I use wget version "BusyBox v1.26.2 (2017-06-11 06:38:32 GMT) multi-call binary."

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to URL Encode the @:

```
wget -m ftp://user%40domain:password@ip.of.old.host
```